# Unable to configure resource mapping in spring framework 4.2.1 release

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I tried develop web project using spring framework 4.2.1 release
But raised error in resource mapping.
I can't find mapped resources(image,css,javascript, etc.)

**-myservices-servlet.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.mv.services"/>   

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                 <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="preparerFactoryClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringBeanPreparerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10485"/>
    </bean>  

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" />
        <property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"/>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"/>
    </bean>
```

If enter resource URL in browser windows, the following error happend

```
21-Sep-2015 14:02:08.293 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [mvservices] in context with path [/mvservices] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:488)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.isCompatibleWithConditionalRequests(ServletWebRequest.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:240)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

Help me ,what's reason?

**-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvservices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvservices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

currently I'm developing this project in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 with Apache Tomcat 8.0.15.0

Comment: Can you show us your `web.xml` ? Do you have filter(s) configured ? Which version of Tomcat are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to reproduce this issue in a [dedicated repro project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues/tree/master/SPR-13516).

It seems the response comes with an HTTP response status of value `"0"` which breaks the parsing algorithm. I'd like to know where this value is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Tomcat 8.0.15.0 with Spring 4.2.1.RELEASE

Somehow, the problem is related to the provided servlet library from Tomcat 8.0.15.0 in combination with Spring 4.2.1. Using another Tomcat version solves the problem or upgrading to Spring 4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.